# How to create WAF exclusion for specific HTTP header value

Tags: azure-application-gateway, azure-waf

We have an OWASP rule that is wrongfully being hit for a specific website, say *xyz.com*

How can we create an exclusion in the Azure WAF policy for that rule only for this specific website? I was trying to make an exclusion based on the Host header value, but it seems I cannot make the combination `RequestHeaderName equals "Host" and RequestHeaderValue equals "xyz.com"`

[image]

Is this even possible with Azure WAF?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use a Custom Rule to achieve this as it allows multiple conditions (the logical AND you require)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/web-application-firewall/ag/custom-waf-rules-overview

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

***I tried to reproduce the same issue in my environment and got the below results***

*It is possible to created WAF Exclusion for specific HTTP Header values*

*I have created the Application gateway WAF policy*

[image]

*I have created the Azure WAF Policy rule for specific example*

*Click on* ***managed identity*** *in the polices, click on* ***Add exclusions***  *and Click on add rules, search for headers which we have to add rules and click on* ***confirm submission***

[image]

*Here the rules are added so we have to Select specific parts of incoming requests to exclude. All other items in the request will be evaluated here*

[image]

*This rule sets protects the application from the common threats defined in the OWASP categories, the rules are updated as needed for new attack signatures*

[image]

Comment: That is what I initially already tried, but it seems that the selectors are added as 2 separate exclusions which don't act like a logical AND. I.e. it will match for every request that has the Host header and not necessarily the specified value as well.

Comment: Thankyou for the reply @EsTeGe , WAF is a set of policies that help determine what traffic is malicious and safe. In this case, when we want to restrict entire traffic from HTTP headers, we can use the "Contains" operator and select all respective rules.